# How to access database which runs on host from inside of container?

Tags: database, docker, localhost, docker-compose

I run my app inside container and map 8080 -> 5000 and it works. However I would like to access Postgres database which runs ON HOST system and not inside other container. Let's say pg runs on `postgres://localhost:5434/mydb` - how I can connect to that db from my app container?

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  image: myprofile/myimage:latest
  ports:
    - 8080:5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a simple answer to this question.

Basically you have 2 options:

1) Use `volumes` to make the socket available in container.

> Databases, such as postgres & mysql, support listening on unix domain
>   sockets instead of TCP sockets. The advantages here are that you can
>   forward unix domain sockets into a container via a volume mount
>   `docker run -v`

2) Use `socat` to provide a localhost(127.0.0.1) tcp connection inside the host from a socket

> For applications which only tcp sockets, I just throw `socat` into the
>   image, and start it up in the background inside the container (having
>   it listen on 127.0.0.1, and forward to the named socket).

Localhost on the host is local only. You can only share localhost's if you are in the same net namespace.
So you can either `--net=host` or you don't use `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Check how to deal with a volume in the docker docs

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/

the VOLUME directive in a Dockerfile

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume

and the -v of `docker run` command

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#run

extract

`-v, --volume=[]               Bind mount a volume`

Comment: I want to connect to database which RUNS ON HOST

Comment: @user606521 this answer is valid!. Not a direct answer but can help you with what you want

Comment: It does not provide me any information on how to connect database from HOST to CONTAINER

Comment: @user606521 Is your question about `HOST` to `CONTAINER` or `CONTAINER` to `localhost`?, These are 2 different scenarios

Comment: As an example, extract from "Dockerizing PostgreSQL" https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/`# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]`

Comment: another example, a `docker run` from "Dockerizing a CouchDB service" at https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/couchdb_data_volumes/  `$ COUCH1=$(docker run -d -p 5984 -v /var/lib/couchdb shykes/couchdb:2013-05-03)`

Comment: No, database is already running on host, and it wont be dockerized. Its available at localhost:5434 -> and I want to access it from inside of container